How to change column type at a specific column position in R?
I have a dataframe called 'data' and am iterating through its column converting them from "comman-seperated" format to number format:
for(i in 1:data_col) {
  if(class(data[1, i]) == 'character' && !is.na(as.numeric(substr(data[1, i], 1, 1)))) {
    data[1:data_row, i] = as.numeric(gsub(",", "", data[1:data_row, i]))
  }
}

The thing is at columns which are character type. This assignment converts the right-side to character than assigns the result to data[1:data_row, i], which is so frustrating. Is there anyway I can convert the ith column to numeric type after converting it to "correct format"? Thanks!

You can first identify those columns that are character class using which and sapply and just loop through those, using the same gsub approach as follows:
char_cols <- which(sapply(data,class)=="character")
for (cc in char_cols) {
  data[,cc] <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",data[,cc]))
}

Also, assuming that 1:data_row refers to all rows of your data, omitting a row reference and only having a column reference will update all rows: data[,cc] here means all rows of column cc.
Alternatively, as the entire data column is being converted, we can use lapply to assign the results directly back to the data.frame and avoid the for() loop entirely
char_cols <- which(sapply(data,class)=="character")
data[char_cols] <- lapply(data[char_cols],
                          function(data_col) as.numeric(gsub(",","",data_col)))


We could use dplyr and readr::parse_number() from tidyverse to change the columns currently of class character to numeric.

[readr::parse_number()] parses the first number it finds, dropping any non-numeric characters
before the first number and all characters after the first number. The
grouping mark specified by the locale is ignored inside the number.

library(tidyverse)
mtcars2 |> 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), parse_number))


Another approach is to simply use dplyr::mutate_at(data, c(i), as.integer).

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Note that mutate_at() and friends have been superseded in favor of across() as used in @JonSpring’s answer.
